# I can not get my if statement to work. Learning to code bash and have researched but can't see the error

Tags: bash, loops, if-statement

I am very new to bash scripting and always having issues with if/else statements.

In this case I am trying to call the $virus variable which  is in a case statement
( I am studying CyberSec)

```
#!/bin/bash

#A script to display the top 5 most destructive computer viruses.

# Lets add colour

RED="\033[31m"
BROWN="\033[33m"
NORMAL="\033[0m"
BLACK="\033[30m"
BLUE="\033[34m"
GREEN="\033[32m"
PURPLE="\033[35m"
CYAN="\033[36m"
GREY="\033[37m"


# Fancy Title

echo -e "${BLUE}Top 5 Most ${RED}Destructive${BLUE}Computer Viruses${NORMAL}" | cowsay

#Password is Cyber

#read -s -p "Due to the Sensitive Nature of this information, Please enter your password:" pass
#if echo $pass | sha256sum -c Hash.txt #check the password via sha256sum
#then echo -e "${GREEN}Access Granted ${NORMAL}"
#else exit 0
#fi


# quit loop
#q=exit

#while true 
#do
#if [ "$x" = "q" ]
#    then
#        exit
#fi
#done

#Display the top 5
echo -e "${BLUE} Please Select A Virus to Learn About"
echo -e "${CYAN} 5. WannaCry -- ${RED}4 Billion: "
echo -e "${CYAN} 4. ILoveYou -- ${RED}15 Billion: "
echo -e "${CYAN} 3. Klez -- ${RED}19.8 Billion: "
echo -e "${CYAN} 2. SoBig -- ${RED}30 Billion: "
echo -e "${CYAN} 1. MyDoom -- ${RED}38 Billion: "
echo -e "${CYAN}Type the number of the virus you wish to learn about:${NORMAL} " 
read virus
# create a case statement to display the names.
case $virus in
    5) echo -e "The 2017 WannaCry computer virus is ransomware, a virus that takes over your computer (or cloud files) and holds them hostage.\nThe WannaCry ransomware ripped through computers in 150 countries, causing massive productivity losses as businesses, hospitals, and government organizations that didn’t pay were forced to rebuild systems from scratch.
The malware raged like wildfire through 200,000 computers worldwide.\nIt stopped when a 22-year-old security researcher in the U.K. found a way to turn it off. Computers with out-of-date operating systems were hit especially hard. \n That’s why security experts always recommend updating your systems frequently.";;
    4) echo -e "The year 2000’s ILOVEYOU virus worked by sending a bogus “love letter” that looked like a harmless text file. Like Mydoom, this attacker sent copies of itself to every email address in the infected machine’s contact list. Shortly after its May 4 release, it had spread to more than 10 million PCs.
The virus was created by a college student in the Philippines named Onel de Guzman. Lacking funds, he wrote the virus to steal passwords so he could log into online services he wanted to use for free. He reportedly had no idea how far his creation would spread. This virus is also known as Loveletter.";;
    3) echo -e "Klez is a close third on the list of the worst computer viruses ever created. With nearly 20 billion in estimated damages, it infected about 7.2% of all computers in 2001, or 7 million PCs. The Klez worm sent fake emails, spoofed recognized senders and, among other things, attempted to deactivate other viruses.
As with other viruses and worms, Klez was released in several variants. It infected files, copied itself, and spread throughout each victim’s network. It hung around for years, with each version more destructive than the last.
Windows has come a long way since most of the computer viruses on this list hit the web. Thankfully, built-in protection with Microsoft Defender is always on the watch.";;
    2) echo -e "The 2003 Sobig computer virus is actually another worm. It is second only to the Mydoom virus in its scope. The $30 billion figure is a worldwide total, including Canada, the U.K., the U.S., mainland Europe, and Asia. Several versions of the worm were released in quick succession, named Sobig.A through Sobig.F, with Sobig.F being the most damaging.
This cybercriminal program masqueraded as legitimate computer software attached to emails. It disrupted ticketing at Air Canada and interfered with countless other businesses. Despite its widespread damage, the creator of the successful bug was never caught.";;
    1) echo -e "The worst computer virus outbreak in history, Mydoom caused estimated damage of $38 billion in 2004, but its inflation-adjusted cost is actually $52.2 billion. Also known as Novarg, this malware is technically a “worm,” spread by mass emailing. At one point, the Mydoom virus was responsible for 25% of all emails sent.
Mydoom scraped addresses from infected machines, then sent copies of itself to those addresses. It also roped those infected machines into a web of computers called a botnet that performed distributed denial of service (DDoS) attacks. These attacks were intended to shut down a target website or server.
Mydoom is still around today, generating 1% of all phishing emails. That’s no small feat considering the 3.4 billion phishing emails sent each day. By that figure, Mydoom has taken on a life of its own, infecting enough poorly-protected machines to send 1.2 billion copies of itself per year, 16 years after its creation.
Though a $250,000 reward was offered, the developer of this dangerous computer worm was never caught.";;
    *) echo "${RED}Please select a number between 1 and 5${NORMAL}";;
esac
sleep 2

read -p "Would you like to learn about another virus? yes/no :  " y
if [ $y = "yes" ]; then 
echo "$virus";
else echo -e "Good-bye";
fi

exit
```

The else part works fine.
if 'yes' is entered the script recalls the number I entered in the question I made "What irus would you like to learn about" there is five selection 1 - 5 to choose from.

Confusing I guess. I simply want the information in the case statement to display when the user answers yes.

Edited to add all the code..

Comment: Run your script through https://shellcheck.net and implement its suggestions.

Comment: Confusing, yes. You set `$virus` to be a number between 1 and 5, and when you ``echo $virus``, you get a number between 1 and 5?  What did you expect?  What is your question?

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: *I simply want the information in the case statement to display when the user answers yes*. Your code contains no *case* statement.

Comment: To understand more clearly as what your script is trying to achieve, we need to look at your code, including the part of `case` statements as well...thanks!

Comment: Hi I have added the entire script.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to start only with this:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Would you like to learn about another virus? yes/no:  " y
if [ "$y" = "yes" ]; then
  echo "virus"
else
  echo "Good-bye"
fi
```

Comment: Hi I have added the enitre script please advise

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your `echo` commands inside the `case` conditions : `2` and `1`.

You need to escape `\` the characters : `$` and `"` inside `echo` to print them literally.

Example: `echo "This is \$5 \"bill\"."`

Output:

```
This is $5 "bill".
```